How do I perform interprocedural analysis on rust programs
I am currently working on scanning unsoundness issues in Rust projects and have made some progress. However, I am now facing some difficulties. Consider the following simple code example. For more detailed information, you can refer to this issue:
https://github.com/rust-bio/rust-htslib/issues/459
pub struct HeaderView {
    pub inner: *mut htslib::bcf_hdr_t,
}

impl HeaderView {
    pub fn new(inner: *mut htslib::bcf_hdr_t) -> Self {
        HeaderView { inner }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn inner(&self) -> htslib::bcf_hdr_t {
        unsafe { *self.inner }
    }

    /// Get vector of sample names defined in the header.
    pub fn samples(&self) -> Vec<&[u8]> {
        let names =
            unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(self.inner().samples, self.sample_count() as usize) };
        names
            .iter()
            .map(|name| unsafe { ffi::CStr::from_ptr(*name).to_bytes() })
            .collect()
    }
}

In this case, the samples function, or more specifically the inner function, is unsound because it indirectly calls self.inner through slice::from_raw_parts. When we look at the inner function, it directly dereferences a raw pointer, which is inherently unsafe in Rust. Additionally, users can create a null pointer for HeaderView using the pub new function or even the pub inner field of HeaderView. Subsequently, calling inner on such a pointer would result in undefined behavior (UB).
Currently, I am only able to scan pub functions, such as samples, as I typically consider them to be user-accessible (though this is not entirely accurate, as modules can also be private). While I can detect such pub functions, I discovered this particular issue only by coincidence, meaning I am unable to identify similar unsound functions like inner() systematically.
One idea I have is to construct an Interprocedural Control Flow Graph (ICFG) for Rust to perform interprocedural analysis. However, I am not sure what tool can achieve this. At the LLVM level, unsafe information might be lost, but I could not find existing tools for interprocedural analysis at the MIR level either.
I hope I can do interprocedural analysis of rust programs to solve the difficulty of cross-function analysis, maybe a simple inline can solve this problem, but I don't know how to inline rust source code.
